# Ito's integral from the definition

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am doing Oksendal's book exercises one by one. I got stuck in 3.2.

I need to prove, from the definition that

$$\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2\text{d}B_s=\frac{B_s^3}{3}-\int_{0}^{t}B_s\text{d}s,$$

where $B_s$ is Brownian motion and the integral is Ito's.

Denote $B_{t_i}$ by $B_i$, for a partition $\{t_i\}_{i=2}^n$.

$$B_t^3=\sum_{0}^{n-1}\left(B_{i+1}^3-B_{i}^3\right)=\sum_{0}^{n-1}\left(B_{i+1}^2+B_{i+1}B_i+B_i^2\right)\left(B_{i+1}-B_i\right)$$

From the third terms we get $\int_{0}^{t}B_s^2\text{d}B_s$. I could add and subtract $B_i$ to the $B_{i+1}$ to make appear sums like $\sum(B_{i+1}-B_i)^2$, which tend to the quadratic covariation ($=t$), but there remain still some sums, like $\sum (B_{i+1}-B_i)^3$ that I don't know how to handle.

**Nevermind!** I got the idea. I will keep the post so you can enjoy. I just looked again to the integral in the right-hand side and the $(t_{i+1}-t_i)$ that appear in the sums. Replaced them conveniently.

Comment: If one wants to solve this exercise rigorously, it is quite a bit of work. If anyone is interested in a full proof, let me know.

Comment: @saz I assumed known $\sum(B_{i+1}-B_i)^2\to t$, which is a previous (2.17) exercise.

Comment: Yes, of course. But in $$\int_0^t B_s^2 \, dB_s = \frac{B_s^3}{3} - \int_0^t B_s \, ds$$ there is no $t$-term, right? So I still don't get how you end up with the correct result.

Comment: @saz The $\text{d}s$ under the integral sign on the right is a $t$-term in disguise. These times the $B_s$ give the $B_s^3$ that appear in the limit of the left-hand side.

Comment: Yes, but it is not that obvious that $$\sum_i B_i (B_{i+1}-B_i)^2$$ converges to $$\int_0^t B_s \, ds.$$ However, you seem to be certain that you are correct and I know how to prove it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know my way around analysis. What remains is only the brute force part. I just have never done Ito's calculus before (i.e. the quadratic covariation of the Brownian motion is not always on my RAM) and had forgotten to look at the right-hand side to see where the cubes were going to go.